# What is the point of Chaos;Head if it’s not in the same worldline as the other Science Adventure entries?

Tags: steins-gate, robotics-notes, chaos-head

I noticed that Chaos;Head’s divergence ratio is different than the one of Steins;Gate and Robotics;Notes. What was the point of that series to begin with since nothing basically happened?

Answer (score 2):

**Because the point of *Science Adventure* series is not really about divergence ratio or the same worldline, but just *due to the official genre/theme.***

Back in 2008, when *Chaos;Head* was first released, the genre was officially given as "Delusional *Science Adventure*" (妄想**科学ADV**). At that time, there was no plan of making this into a series.

It was not until 2009 when *Steins;Gate* was released with the genre as "Supposition *Science Adventure*" (想定**科学ADV**), making it a series and also the 2nd entry.

This is then followed by:

- *Robotics;Note*: Expansive *Science Adventure* (拡張**科学ADV**)
- *Chaos;Child*: Delusional *Science Adventure* (the same as *Chaos;Head*)
- *Occultic;Nine*: Paranormal *Science Adventure* (超常**科学ADV**)
- *Anonymous;Code*: Supposition *Science Adventure* (the same as *Steins;Gate*)

The series emphasizes real scientific elements heavily while still allowing them to mix with fictional elements. This includes, but not strictly limited to, time travel and divergence ratio.

---

Main reference: [Japanese Wikipedia on *Science Adventure Series*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81)